# How to use abs, sqrt etc on OperateOnAll with OjAlgo?

Tags: java, ojalgo

I'm trying to take square root on all elements in a matrix `A` by doing the following command.

```
A.operateOnAll()
```

But the argument must be `UnaryFunction<N>` and I don't know how to create that.
I reading the API documention, but still don't know how to create a sqrt procedure for matrix `A`

https://javadoc.scijava.org/ojAlgo/index.html?org/ojalgo/function/FunctionSet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UnaryFunction<Double> modifier = PrimitiveMath.ROOT.parameter(2);

// To modify A in place
A.modifyAll(modifier);

// The results in another matrix
A.operateOnAll(modifier).supplyTo(B);

// To have a new results matrix created for you
MatrixStore<Double> C = A.operateOnAll(modifier).get();

// If A if of an immutable type like Primitive64Matrix
DenseReceiver mutable = A.copy();
mutable.modifyAll(modifier);
Primitive64Matrix B = mutable.get();
```

Comment: Tackar! Can I use something similar for Primitive64Matrix?

Comment: That's an immutable type! I edited the example to show what you need to do in that case.